# Prove: the canonical ringhomomorphism $f: \mathbb Z \rightarrow R/I = \mathbb Z[i]/ \langle5+3i \rangle$ is surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $R = \mathbb Z[i]$,   $z=5+3i$ and $I=\langle z\rangle$.

**I've shown:**

- $z$ is not a prime element in $R$
- $R/I$ is not a field
- $1+i\notin R^*$
- $(5+3i)/(1+i) \in R$
- $-21+i \in I$

**To prove:**

The canonical ringhomomorphism $f: \mathbb Z \rightarrow R/I$ is surjective.

**My ideas:**

I know $1 \in \mathbb Z \mapsto [1] \in R/I$, so I must show 
$\forall ([x=a+bi] \in  R/I)\exists z \in \mathbb N: [x] = [z]\land x-z\in I=\langle 5+3i\rangle$.

Also i've computed that $[34] = [0]$ so char$R/I \le 34$.

Comment: I do not understand when you say $R=\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $1+i\notin R$

Comment: typo: $1+i \notin R^*$

Comment: by canonical map you mean $x\rightarrow x+xi$?

Comment: No, I mean $x \mapsto [x]$ that is the only map mentioned in my book.

Comment: what is $[x]$ and your $\forall ([x=a+bi] \in  R/I)\exists z \in \mathbb N: [x] = [\sum_{n=1}^z 1=z]\land x-z\in I=\langle 5+3i\rangle$ is not quite readable... please consider editing that

Comment: $[x]$ is just the left coset $\in \mathbb R/I$. There exists just one ringhomomorphism $\mathbb Z \rightarrow R$ for any ring $R$ since $1 \mapsto 1 \in R$. I've edited a bit, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that $i$ is in the same coset as an integer in the quotient, since $\mathbb{Z}\to R=\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has image $\mathbb{Z}$. But as you say, $-21+i\in I$.

Comment: Could you please specify with what map are you working? I could not realize what $[x]$ is for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$.. It is not mentioned in the question at least...

Comment: I was assuming that $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}[i]:n\mapsto n+0i$, so that $f(n) = n + I$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: There exists just one ringhomomorphism $\mathbb Z \rightarrow R$ for any ring $R$, since $1 \mapsto 1 \in R$.

Comment: @rogerl : I doubt that is not canonical... I am not sure but i guess it is not...

Comment: Doh, I should have realized that. Since $-21+i \in I$ for any $a+bi \in \mathbb Z[i]$ I just solve the equation $[-21+i][b]+[z] = [a+bi]$ for $z \in \mathbb Z$. Thus it sufficices to choose $z = a + b(21)$ since then $z \mapsto [z] = [a+b(21)] = [a+b(21)] + [0] = [a+b(21)] + [b][-21+i] = [a+bi]$